ARCore and TFLite inference on GPU stalling both
I have opened this very issue in the ARCore SDK repositories, you can find it here.
SPECIFIC ISSUE ENCOUNTERED
I am running AR Core for motion tracking using the android SDK, basically at the state of the hello_ar_kotlin sample.
When running inference on (separate!) image data, while TFLite can access the GPU, both systems break down when being run together, with ARCore dropping to 2-3 FPS and TFLite to 1 FPS.
VERSIONS USED

Android Studio: Iguana 2023.2.1
ARCore SDK for Android: com.google.ar:core:1.42.0
Device manufacturer, model, and O/S: Google, Pixel 7, Android 14
Google Play Services for AR (ARCore):

versionName=1.44.241490493
signatures=PackageSignatures{c31e10a version:3, signatures:[fd17c870], past signatures:[53bcc66f flags: 17, fd17c870 flags: 17]}


Output of adb shell getprop ro.build.fingerprint:

google/panther/panther:14/AP1A.240305.019.A1/11445699:user/release-keys

STEPS TO REPRODUCE THE ISSUE
Dependencies
// for ARCore
implementation("com.google.ar:core:1.42.0")
implementation("de.javagl:obj:0.2.1")
// for TFLite
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-tflite-impl:16.1.0")
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-tflite-java:16.1.0")
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-tflite-support:16.1.0")
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-tflite-gpu:16.2.0")
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-tflite-acceleration-service:16.0.0-beta01")


Clone hello_ar_kotlin.
Add TFLite (Interpreter API), e.g. TensorFlow Lite Inference.
Run ARCore and TFLite inference simultaneously.
Performance of both will drop to unusable levels.

WORKAROUNDS (IF ANY)
None found yet.
ADDITIONAL COMMENTS
I cannot use MLKit with ARCore as

I am running inference on images obtained from a separate device (hence I cannot run inference on image data provided by ARCore)
MLKit seems to be a thin wrapper around the TFLite Tasks API and the use case I have is not provided by tasks, i.e. I need to use the Interpreter API

GPU Memory usage of TFLite alone seems to be 771 MB on average. GPU Memory usage with ARCore together seems to be about 810 MB on average, so not that much more.
Ressource profiling data obtained with Android GPU inspector
